# Share stream of data to other applications on Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have an application that receives data via the USB port. The amount of data is usually small but in certain cases it can raise up to 20-30kB/s.

Now I want to share this data to other applications/activities running in different processes and I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

As I understand the main method of IPC in Android is Binder. Although they always advertise it as fast I don't think it can handle a few kB of data per second. The main reason for this is, as I see it, that it sends and receives Parcels. Parcels are not blazingly fast. However beside Parcel I've seen that Binder can also use ashmem to share data. This mechanism would certantly be fast enough but I haven't found any examples.

Currently the idea is to use the Android Content provider classes. I dont know how this works under the hood but I'm almost certain that they use Binder. But I've read that you can transfer media streams with it so I guess it should work.

If I was on normal Linux platform I would use UNIX sockets. But on Android I'm not sure if it can be done easily from the Java side.

So to recap:
20-30kB of data per second.

- Binder ?
- Content provider ?
- Sockets ?
- Suggestions ...